# Correct way to compare a metric to itself in Prometheus, to detect increase or decrease in rate

Tags: prometheus

Given a metric `my_http_counter`, with its own labels which I can query with

```
sum(rate(my_http_counter[1m])) by (label)
```

I'm looking for the correct way to detect an increase of more than, say 2% over the last 5 minutes.

I though of:

```
sum(rate(my_http_counter[1m] offset 5m)) by (label) /
sum(rate(my_http_counter[1m])) by (label)
```

but, I'm not sure about this.

I can compare two metrics which overlap, but I'm looking for the correct way to compare a mertic to its previous state.

Thank you.

Comment: [`delta`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta)?

Comment: "delta should only be used with gauges and native histograms.." and in my case, we're dealing with a counter :)

Comment: Then [`increase`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) i guess.

Comment: thank you, I'm aware of the function choice, but I'm more looking into the correct query. as mentioned I have an idea or two, but I don't think my ideas will catch the change I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should detect an increase of more than 2% for the `rate(my_http_counter[1m])` during the last 5 minutes:

```
(
  sum(rate(my_http_counter[1m])) by (label)
    /
  sum(rate(my_http_counter[1m] offset 5m)) by (label)
) > 1.02
```

It uses the [offset modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier) for fetching values for the same series 5 minutes ago.

Another option is to use [Prometheus subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) with the [delta](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#delta) function:

```
(
  delta(
    (sum(rate(my_http_counter[1m])) by (label))[5m:1m]
  )
    /
  sum(rate(my_http_counter[1m])) by (label)
) > 0.02
```

It may be worth wrapping the query into [abs()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#abs) before comparing to `0.02` in order to catch both increases and decreases by more than 2% over the last 5 minutes:

```
abs(
  delta(
    (sum(rate(my_http_counter[1m])) by (label))[5m:1m]
  )
    /
  sum(rate(my_http_counter[1m])) by (label)
) > 0.02
```

Comment: Thank you. I assume you're aware that `delta` is better not used on counters - but the fact we're using subquery makes this a legit action ?

Comment: or, maybe because we're wrapping `sum(rate` , then the value given is legal to pass to delta ?